# How to store individual CSS styling in a database?

Tags: javascript, css, firebase, vue.js, vuefire

Thank you for helping people and contributing to the open source.

I have a Vue.js to-do app. Data is stored in firebase via vue-fire and firestore.
I have a function which checks the todo item done by clicking it. But this styling disappears whenever the page is refreshed.

How can I make "line-through" style(or any other) get stored in the data so that even when refreshed it stays there?

```
   <template>
      <div class="pt-3">
        <div v-show="showText == true" class="text">
          <h2>Get started by adding a new todo.</h2>
          <p>Click on the item to check it done.</p>
          <p class="warnings">This is a prototype app. Please do not input any sensitive information!</p>
        </div>
        <v-row class="addtodo d-flex justify-center">
          <v-col cols="8">
            <v-text-field
              class="addtext"
              label="New Todo"
              outlined
              v-model="newItem"
              @keyup.enter="addItem"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="1">
            <v-btn class="btn" large color="primary" :disabled="newItem == ''" @click="addItem">Add</v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <transition-group class="d-flex flex-column justify-center align-center" name="fade">
          <v-card
            class="d-flex justify-center align-center ma-2 text-left"
            width="400"
            v-for="(ToDo, index) in ToDos"
            :key="ToDo.id"
        @click="checked = !checked"
          >
            <v-row class="d-flex justify-space-around">
              <v-col cols="8">
                <v-list-item-title     
            :class="{ done: checked }" class="headline mb-1">{{ index + 1}} - {{ ToDo.name }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-col>
              <v-col class="tools text-right">
                <v-btn class="dicon" icon color="secondary" @click="editToDo(ToDo.id)">
                  <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn class="dicon" icon color="red" @click="deleteToDo(ToDo.id)">
                  <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-card>
        </transition-group>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    
    
    <script>
    import { db } from "../firebase/db";
    
        export default {
      name: "ToDoList",
      data() {
        return {
          ToDos: [],
          ToDo: [],
          newItem: "",
          index: "",
          showText: true,
          checked: false,
          currentlyEditing: null,
          todoEditText: "",
        };
      },
      methods: {
        async addItem() {
          if (this.newItem) {
            await db.collection("ToDos").add({ name: this.newItem });
            this.newItem = "";
          }
          this.deleteText();
        },
        deleteToDo(id) {
          db.collection("ToDos").doc(id).delete();
        },
        deleteText: function () {
          this.showText = false;
        },
      },
      beforeDestroy() {
        clearInterval(this.showText);
      },
      firestore: {
        ToDos: db.collection("ToDos"),
      },
    };
    </script>


<style>
.done {
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

.text {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1vh;
}
.warnings {
  color: red;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30vh;
}
.addtodo {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-right: 30px;
  z-index: 1111;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 4px #888;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 6px;
}
.addtext {
}

.todolist {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: red;
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
}

.tools {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: if the style disappears on page reload then there's maybe an issue with your code not sending update to firebase properly? as based on provided code, you've added dynamic class binding `:class="{ done: checked }"` so it should catch up although I see you use `:class` and `class` attributes there (maybe try switching the order of them first so `class` and then `:class` as it might override something on page render? (just assuming, not sure about that)

Comment: Yes but that's the problem. I can't get it to send that. I don't know how. I have been searching for 2 hours.

Comment: so your question shouldn't be about storing styling in database but connecting to it properly - what request do you send? What response do you receive? (error code maybe?)

Comment: It may be wrong but I explained what I wanted to do. That's just the title and I don't know how to write it better.

Comment: I think I've understood it wrong - sorry - added an answer already - hope that it helps ;)

Comment: Not at all! My English isn't great :) Thank you for the answer! I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `update` method that would enable you update records you have in your database - here's some snippet you can use to apply:

First, bind proper click event (instead existing `@click="checked = !checked"` one):

```
@click="updateTodo(ToDo)"
```

And then in your methods:

```
updateToDo(ToDo) {
  db.collection("ToDos").doc(ToDo.id).patch({ checked: !ToDo.checked })  // <-- not sure if you have .patch method available here to update only 1 property, but I hope you can figure out how to handle that :)
}
```

EDIT (probable answer for 1st comment below):

Not sure how your binding with DB works, but I assume that it might work like that:

```
updateToDo(ToDo) {
  ToDo.checked = !ToDo.checked;
  db.collection("ToDos").doc(ToDo.id).patch({ checked: ToDo.checked });
}
```

Comment: It will be a different question but I am using vuetify and my method of checked = !checked doesnt work anymore or it checks all the todos so I am using this: click="$event.target.classList.toggle('checked')" Is there any way to add this to the code above to update it from database? Thank you. Sorry for the question

Comment: @sunflowerseed I've updated my answer, but I'm not sure if that's gonna work as you wish - please let me know if it works (and if not, then please tell me what DB plugin/controller do you use so I might help with that)